# Identify data on the last available date in r

Tags: r

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(X = c("cc_China", "bb_China", "dd_China", "cc_Egypt", 
"bb_Egypt", "dd_Egypt"), Country = c("China", "China", "China", 
"Egypt", "Egypt", "Egypt"), May = c(2, 3, 8, 2, 4, 1), Jun = c(2, 
2, 5, 5, 5, 5), Jul = c(3, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA), Aug = c(4, 6, 3, 
2, 3, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have a dataset as such, I have extract the country from X column into the Country column. For each country, I wish to get the latest month and their value, where all 3 different row (cc,bb and dd) are not NA. For China, the latest is Aug where, all cc,bb and dd have values. For Egypt, the latest month would be Jun, where it was the latest month where all 3 datas are available. Thanks.

```
  df1> 
   X        Country   May   Jun   Jul   Aug
 cc_China   China       2     2     3     4
 bb_China   China       3     2    NA     6
 dd_China   China       8     5    NA     3
 cc_Egypt   Egypt       2     5     3     2
 bb_Egypt   Egypt       4     5     2     3
 dd_Egypt   Egypt       1     5    NA    NA
```

I wish to get this

```
  Month    X        Value
   Aug   cc_China     4
   Aug   bb_China     6
   Aug   dd_China     3
   Jun   cc_Egypt     5
   Jun   bb_Egypt     5
   Jun   dd_Egypt     5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the data in long format and for each `Country` keep only those rows which have all non-NA values in a month. For each `Country` you can then keep only the max month.

Since we cannot compare character month names directly, I have converted them to numbers using inbuilt vector `month.abb`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(X, Country), names_to = 'Month') %>%
  mutate(month_num = match(Month, month.abb)) %>%
  group_by(Country, Month) %>%
  filter(all(!is.na(value))) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  filter(month_num == max(month_num)) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-month_num, -Country)

#  X        Month value
#  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#1 cc_China Aug       4
#2 bb_China Aug       6
#3 dd_China Aug       3
#4 cc_Egypt Jun       5
#5 bb_Egypt Jun       5
#6 dd_Egypt Jun       5
```